# Django TemplateDoesNotExist. Django doesn't check one of the my apps, when looking for templates

Tags: django, django-templates

Django can't find needed template from my app. I named directory `"app/template/app/template.html"`, my settings:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Also I add my app name in INSTALED_APPS.
I tried move my template in project's directory and its work! But I just wanna understand, why loader didn't check my app directory

Comment: The path should be `app/templates/app/template.html`.

Comment: It's mistake. I named it in project right like u write